# Git merge/compare tool setup

Tags: git, compare

I'm trying to setup CodeCompare as my git merge/diff tool, however I keep getting an error that the following line is incorrect in my .gitconfig file, I am on windows using msysgit

```
 cmd = "C:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\codemerge.exe" "/TF=$REMOTE" "/MF=$LOCAL" "/RF=$MERGED" "/BF=$BASE"
```

My merge section looks as follows

```
[merge]
tool = codecompare
[mergetool "codecompare"]
cmd = "C:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\codemerge.exe" "/TF=$REMOTE" "/MF=$LOCAL" "/RF=$MERGED" "/BF=$BASE"
keepBackup = false
trustExitCode = false
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Did you try with `TF="$REMOTE" /MF="$LOCAL" /BF="$BASE" /RF="$MERGED" /REMOVEFILES /B`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found this works better

http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/git-devart-codecompare-integration/

```
[diff]
    tool = codecompare
    guitool = codecompare
[merge]
    tool = codecompare 
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
[difftool "codecompare"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Devart/Code Compare/CodeCompare.exe' \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    renames = true
[mergetool "codecompare"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Devart/Code Compare/CodeMerge.exe' -MF=\"$LOCAL\" -TF=\"$REMOTE\" -BF=\"$BASE\" -RF=\"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following configuration:

```
[difftool "codecompare"]
   cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codecompare.exe' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
   renames = true
[diff]
   tool = codecompare
[mergetool "codecompare"]
   cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Devart\\Code Compare\\codemerge.exe' /MF="$LOCAL" /TF="$REMOTE" /BF="$BASE" /RF="$MERGED"
   trustExitCode = true
[mergetool]
   keepBackup = false
[merge]
   tool = codecompare
```

Comment: This did not work for me as posted. It did however work after escaping the double quotation marks in the two `cmd` parameters.

Comment: See workaround here - [Using CodeMerge with Git Bash](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=24463).